# Independence module (browser-based) for other types of LRS (LMS)

Tags: scorm2004, tin-can-api

Is it possible create Tin-Can module (for example it's simple html page with quize) for all type of LRS?
For SCORM it was possible. Because there was possible find typical scorm-API-object in parent pages (like API_1484_11). So this module is independent. I can include it to anywhere LMS and it will work.
What about Tin-Can? I must develop each module for each LRS specially? 
Thanx.

Comment: "all type of LRS" - since the content is set to work against a endpoint, are you referring to being able to work directly with the local LRS vs. one thats been hardcoded?

Comment: I'm referring black box design. I shouldn't set endpoint (URL) into zip-module.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is "yes" and "no", and "coming soon".

SCORM is effectively a specification for package, import, launch, and play of content with a data model and communication protocol. Tin Can (or really Experience API/xAPI) is a data model format and communication protocol, without any provision for the package, import, launch and play of content. This is what an **LRS** implements. This is incredible flexibility, really too much for the typical (majority) e-learning landscape as it exists in 2016. Hence the answer of "no".

With the 0.9 version of the Tin Can specification (at the time it was Project Tin Can) there was release of a set of "LMS Guidelines" that suggested how xAPI could be used in a typical e-learning landscape, they are found here: https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/launch/blob/master/lms_lrs.md They are what the major authoring tools such as Captivate, Storyline, Lectora, etc. implemented and results in a "Tin Can Package" (a zip with a `tincan.xml` file). Those guidelines provided package, import, and launch. However they were relatively restrictive, weren't vetted over the last 4 years by the community at large, and aren't on a standards path. More problematically they still weren't providing for a complete "data model" (still only a "data model format" aka xAPI statements), in other words there was no definition of how to capture in a standard way content "completion" or whether something was "passed" or "failed", etc. This does enable you to create one package that can **communicate** with any conformant LRS, and be imported and launched in any "launching system" (LMS or LMS like system) that implemented those guidelines. But leaves open what the statements will be and what data will be captured. Hence the answer of "yes".

At the beginning of June 2016 (a couple weeks away at time of writing) the cmi5 working group intends to release for production use the cmi5 specification, found at https://github.com/AICC/CMI-5_Spec_Current/blob/quartz/cmi5_spec.md. This is an open specification, developed by members of the xAPI community, that is intended for the typical e-learning landscape (LMSs) that provides for package, import, launch of content with a data model and uses the xAPI communication protocol. It is intended to be implemented by "launching systems" (my term) (LMS or LMS like system) which are tightly integrated with an xAPI LRS. It includes specification of how to capture events of a learning session, in a registration, such as launches, session initialization and termination, pass, fail, and completion of units of activity (Assignable Units or AUs) in sets of larger instruction (Blocks) in an overall Course structure. With cmi5 you should be able to create a package, import it, launch individual pieces of content (locally or remotely hosted), communicate defined pieces of information back to an LRS, and then report on specific pieces of learning data. This is important work a long time in the making, but unfortunately it will take time to see adoption in current e-learning products. Hence the answer of "coming soon".

Comment: Thank for answer, Brian. But I still understand.

Ok, I'll ask simplify.
For example. I just have some packaged content.
Can I use it by different LRS.LMS? Or I must repack it before?

Comment: @user5555232 what package standard is the "packaged" content? What .xml files (if any) does it contain at the root of the zip, presuming it is a zip? What generated the package?

Comment: I'm developer of e-learning apps. I've got a lot of SCORM-modules. Usually it is html-pages with Flash. Of course it's into zip-package. And I can sell this packages for everything types of LMS without any changes. As is. And I know it will work normally.

Now I see some orders to TC-modules. May be it was written stupid, but there is similar requirements like as SCORM - for some abstract LRS/LMS (as universal).

Comment: So, I shouldn't know URL and type of LRS/LMS. I shouldn't know name of user. I must make TC-module as black box.
But while I don't understand is it possible? I see I need know URL before packing zip of TC.

My be anybody shared me simple sample?